# PHP: why is shell_exec not working with unix time command?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I'm using shell_exec to execute a python file with a few variables and then print the `real`, `user`, and `sys` results to the console.

```
 shell_exec("time /Users/$USER/anaconda/bin/python 
                           /Applications/MAMP/cgi-bin/file.py 
                                          $var1 $var2 $var3", $result );

    print_r($result);
```

Although this has worked for me before, it's not working now. The error I'm getting is `PHP Warning:  shell_exec() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

It's the same response whether I just have `time` or `/usr/bin/time`.

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) takes only a single parameter. What you were using before was likely [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

What is in the command string that you're passing it (e.g. `time` or `/usr/bin/time`) is irrelevant to the warning you're getting.